# How to validate email live using javascript and change textbox background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, email, textbox

my java code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#email').keyup(function() {
              var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

              if (re.test($(this).val())) {

                    $(this).css("background-color", "green");

              } else {

                    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
              }
        });
});
</script>
```

my html:

```
<p><b>Email Address:</b> <input type="text" name="email_address" id="email" /> </p>
```

I am looking for a live-update type of effect as the user types, not a click-away affect.

Nothing seems to work, I have used similar code to change values of other text-boxes in a live-fashion. Sorry if this is a repeated question.

Thank you!

Comment: Try harder to describe your problem, what **exactly** you're trying to do, and stuff. We need more help before we're able to help you! :D

Comment: Your code seems to work. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/RjY7H/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is working fine on my computer.
Are you sure you have included jQuery? Which version? What browser are you using?
This is my working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#email').keyup(function () {
                var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

                if (re.test($(this).val())) {

                    $(this).css("background-color", "green");

                } else {

                    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <p><b>Email Address:</b> 
        <input type="text" name="email_address" id="email" />
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

**EDIT:** if you want an easy client validation library I suggest you using [jQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Comment: Thank you, something was wrong with included jQuery statement I suppose, thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: @BitcoinBarron no problem :) If this has solved your problem please consider marking my answer as correct (green tick below the number of votes on the left of the answer text).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use HTML5 validator ?

```
<form>
  <input type="email" placeholder="me@example.com">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

source: http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/How-To-Validate-Email-Addresses-With-Html5.htm
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aunY4/1/

Comment: I am looking for a live-update type of effect as the user types, not a click-away affect, not sure if HTML5 validator allows this?

Comment: Ok no HTML5 validator is triggered when the user press the submit button :). Gonna create a new thing for you. Just wait a bit ;)

Comment: Opps looks like there was something wrong with my jquery imports, thank you very much for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

The only right answer is to not validate it.

http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/?utm_source=buffer&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Buffer&utm_content=bufferdb46a

Comment: The solution in that article leads to a bad user experience, in my opinion. If the user doesn't get an email from you after signing up on your site, there's a good chance they will just assume your site is broken. Few will return to try again. I agree that most regular expressions for email addresses are too strict and will lead to some users being turned away, but doing no validation on the field is not a great alternative.

Comment: From a decade of experience. You cannot validate a email. We hen you are finished with your regular a new form pops up, like .info, or the German letters ä,ü and ö and now they are rolling out .email. Better let the user input the email twice than denying an user access with a valid address the validation fails with.

Comment: I was not advocating for regular expressions, but simply for some kind of validation. Making a user input their address twice is one example.